# Virtualbox - how to give Internet access and internal network access to two VMs?

Tags: networking, virtualbox, ip, nat

I made two Virtualbox virtual machines, CentOS 7 latest iso. I gave them each 2 network interfaces, one NAT and one "Internal network" in order to get them to talk to each other and have Internet access. I set manual IP addresses for each:

NAT interfaces: VM1: 10.0.2.15/24 - VM2: 10.0.2.16/24 Internal Network interfaces: VM1: 10.0.2.1/24 VM2 10.0.2.2/24

My problem is, my SSH port forwarding rules don't work unless I disable the "internal network" interfaces. Once I do, port forwarding starts working again.

How could I fix this? My goals are to have the 2 VMs able to communicate with each other and with Internet access.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try

```
 NAT interfaces: VM1: 10.0.2.15/24 - VM2: 10.0.2.16/24 
 Internal Network interfaces: VM1: 10.0.3.1/24 VM2 10.0.3.2/24
```

You will have trouble using same network on differents interfaces.